# Double(,) and not Double()() from DataTable Using Select

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, select, datatable

I have a DataTable with fields that are Double or String (character).  Using the Select and ToArray methods, how can I fetch columns that I know are double into a multidimensional double array?

For starters, I can fetch Age and Weight columns into a jagged array by using

```
Dim arrayOfDoubles()() As Double = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) {Convert.ToDouble(x("Age")), Convert.ToDouble(x("Weight"))}).ToArray()
```

However, the above results in a jagged, i.e., ()() double array, which I cannot feed into my processing -- and I don't want to write loops to pick off the elements in ()() just to get them into (,).

So, if I know I have 1000 rows, and 20 columns that are double in the DataTable (and know their names), how could I create either a Double(20,1000) array or a Double(1000,20) directly using Select and ToArray?

Also, what if I want to filter age>40, and fetch the same 20 columns, but only 300 rows result.  How can I create either Double(20,300) array or a Double(300,20) from this filtering?

Comment: There are no LINQ operators for 2d arrays, so you need to resort to doing two nested `For Each` and build the 2d array. Is that something you know how to do?

Comment: Can you  change your "processing" so it accepts jagged arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
Dim arrayOfDoubles()() As Double = _
        dt.AsEnumerable() _
            .Select(Function(x) _
            { _
                Convert.ToDouble(x("Age")), _
                Convert.ToDouble(x("Weight")) _
            }) _
            .ToArray()
            
Dim output(arrayOfDoubles.Length, arrayOfDoubles.First().Length) As Double

For i = 0 To arrayOfDoubles.Length - 1
    For j = 0 To arrayOfDoubles.First().Length - 1
        output(i, j) = arrayOfDoubles(i)(j)
    Next
Next
```

For your filtering issue, that's just handled by adding the filtering to `arrayOfDoubles()()` before creating the output.

Comment: Filtering: e.g. `.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) DirectCast(x("Age"), Double) > 40))` or perhaps using datatable Select method (`dt.Select("[Age] > 40")`

Comment: @Enigmativity - thanks, as your syntax will rapidly thrust me forward for dumping into a 2D array.

Comment: As a small fix, I changed `Dim output(arrayOfDoubles.Length, arrayOfDoubles.First().Length) As Double` to `Dim output(arrayOfDoubles.Length - 1, arrayOfDoubles.First().Length - 1) As Double`